# Django can't connect MySQL But MySQL server is normally work

Tags: mysql, django

I Installed mysqlclient for python 3.8.4
and My django Database Setting is this.

```
DATABASES  = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'   : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME'     : 'testdb',
        'USER'     : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : '-------',
        'HOST'     : '127.0.0.2',
        'PORT'     :'3306', 
    }
}
```

[MYSQL Server is Good][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owfW4.png
and I Tested Again that in the vscode. the result it server successfully connect .
so ..My question is.. why Django can't connect MySQl???

```
jun_webserver2) C:\Users\lenovo\TechBlog\Server\Server>py manage.py 
migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line 
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1285, in check
    *cls._check_constraints(databases),
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1877, in _check_constraints
    connection.features.supports_table_check_constraints or
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\features.py", line 104, in supports_column_check_constraints
    if self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 372, in mysql_is_mariadb
    return 'mariadb' in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 359, in mysql_server_info
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value      
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)

(jun_webserver2) C:\Users\lenovo\TechBlog\Server\Server>py manage.py 
migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line 
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases) 
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1285, in check
    *cls._check_constraints(databases),
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1877, in _check_constraints
    connection.features.supports_table_check_constraints or
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\features.py", line 104, in supports_column_check_constraints
    if self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 372, in mysql_is_mariadb
    return 'mariadb' in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 359, in mysql_server_info
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value      
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26,utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in \__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\jun_webserver2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 179,\connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>
```

should i have to downgrade MySQL? I think Django code is nothing wrong. and MySQL wheel is "mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32"

Comment: Did you migrate into the sqlite3 database before? Because then you have to copy the data into your new MySQL. Also try `python manage.py makemigrations` and maybe restart the server

Comment: thanks a lot! i tried before. and i finally fixed this problem! I downgrade the MySQL 8.0 -> 5.7 and my code is nomally work